# Help in Understanding the Estimation Procedure Followed in a Paper

Tags: time-series, forecasting, garch, finance

I would like to build a Markov regime-switching based early warning system. From the several papers I've skimmed through, [1][2][3][4] they go on about estimating a Markov regime-switching model as a first step and on the basis of the filtered probabilities they estimate a logistic regression model. The problem I have concerns the in-sample and the out-of-sample estimation procedure. In the titled "Predicting Extreme Daily Regime Shifts in Financial Time Series Exchange/Johannesburg Stock Exchange—All Share Index," [2] was the Markov regime-switching model estimated on the training sample (80% of the data set going from 2010 to 2020) then re-estimated on the validation sample (the remaining 20%) and the same was done for the logistic tree model? If so, how was it inferred that the probability of realising extreme losses in the next 5 years is 51% when we have just re-estimated the logit model on the remaining 20% of the data? If not, can anyone please clarify how was the estimation and forecasting done.

[1] https://www.researchgate.net/publication/311335511_An_early_warning_system_for_inflation_using_Markov-Switching_and_logistic_models_approach

[2] https://www.mdpi.com/2227-7072/9/2/18

[3] https://www.econbiz.de/Record/an-early-warning-system-for-inflation-in-the-philippines-using-markov-switching-and-logistic-regression-models-cruz-christopher-john/10011260115

[4] https://www.aimspress.com/article/id/2039